# LINQ select from TList?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of `RowData` items (a custom class).

A `RowData` item contains a list of `CellData` items (another custom class).

Currently, the only way I can access each individual `CellData` item is through the `RowData`'s `this[int index]`, which means I'd have to create a loop for each search.

What I want is to create a method that will return all of the `CellData` items for a given `index` value:

```
private List<RowData> rowList;

public IEnumerable<CellData> Cells(int index) {
  foreach (var row in rowList) {
    if (row.ID == index) {
      return row.AsEnumerable<CellData>();
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

I don't like returning `NULL`, and I'd like to know how to accomplish this task using some LINQ techniques ([either *Query* or *Method* syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx)).

Comment: You could return `Enumerable.Empty<CellData>()` in place of `null`. I know that doesn't help with the LINQ part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to use LINQ syntax for getting cells collection from row, your `RowData` need to be enumerable, i.e. implement `IEnumerable` interface.

By `.AsEnumerable<CellData>()` in your example, I assume your `RowData` already implements it and enumerating `RowData` returns collection of `CellData` objects.

If not, you need to implement `IEnumerable` in `RowData` on your own. If your `this[int index]` accessor reads the data from a collection, you can just return that collection's `GetEnumerator`.

And then, you'll be able to fetch `CellData` collection from `RowData` collection using LINQ queries, i.e. like this:

```
var cells = rowList.Where(x => x.ID == index).SelectMany(x => x);
```

Comment: `RowData` actually implements `IList<CellData>`, which (I believe) includes `IEnumerable`. Thanks.

Comment: That's correct. In this case, you can use the query above. Note that if there is more than one row with given ID, cells from all matching rows will be merged. If you don't want that, you need to have some kind of `null`-check.

Comment: I'd also like a way to write a `Select` function, similar to what `System.Data.DataTable` uses that queries on `ColumnName=ColumnValue`. Can this be done in LINQ? I hate to ask a whole new question for something so similar.

Comment: You mean specifying both column name and value in runtime? This can't be done in plain LINQ, but there are some LINQ-style libraries like Dynamic LINQ (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) that can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming only one row is returned given an index:

```
public IEnumerable<CellData> Cells(int index) 
{
    var foundRow = rowList.FirstOrDefault(row => row.ID == index);
    //if no row was found, foundRow will be null
    if(foundRow != null)
        return foundRow.AsEnumerable<CellData>();
    else
        return new CellData[]; //return empty cells IEnumerable. Could also be new List<CellData>()
    }
}
```

This code assumes `foundRow.AsEnumerable<CellData>()` returns a `IEnumerable<CellData>`.

You have to check for nullity, because row at a given index might nor be found.

Comment: OP did not want to return null.

Comment: What option does OP have then, if no row is found? Will change to return an empty list.

Comment: I can't speak for the OP, but I prefer not to return null from methods that return `IEnumerable`. I was just pointing out that the question also included that wish.

Comment: It's OK, it's a valid request. Changed to return an empty IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
List<CellData> cells = rowList.Where(x => x.Index == index).SelectMany(x => x.Cells).ToList();
```

Comment: It will return `IEnumerable` ... use `Find` instead.

Comment: It'll return collection of rows, not cells

Comment: OP wants cells from the searched row, not the found row(s)

Answer (score 0):

This will achieve the same result.

```
 var resultsList = from x in rowList
                      where x.ID == index
                      select x;
 return resultsList;
```

Comment: OP wants cells from the searched row, not the row.

Answer (score 0):

```
public IEnumerable<CellData> Cells(int index){
    var cells = (from r on rowList
                where r.ID == index
                select r.Cells).FirstOrDefault();
    return cells;
}
```

Comment: Once again, OP wants cells from the searched row, not the row(s)